# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id when using getChildFragmentManager() inside viewpager2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

My app structure look like this -

> (Main Activity)->(Fragment 1)->(ViewPager-> Fragment A,Fragment B).

I am getting error when i do fragment transaction inside `Fragment A or B` like this. Note here i am using `getChildFragmentManager()` for fragment transaction.

```
NotificationDetails notificationFragment = NotificationDetails.newInstance(list);
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout, notificationFragment, null);
                        transaction.commit();
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a005b
> (com.example.id/Navigation_Main_Layout) for fragment
> NotificationDetails{eaff8ce} (560448c9-144a-49f8-a4d3-47f491b6a563
> id=0x7f0a005b)

When i call fragment transaction like this. Note here i am using `getSupportFragmentManager()` for fragment transaction.it work perfectly without any issues.

```
NotificationDetails notificationFragment = NotificationDetails.newInstance(list);
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout, notificationFragment, null);
                        transaction.commit();
```

That's my activity layout. You can see the id exist in layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Navigation_parent"
    >



    <!--The Main Layout For Content-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Toolbar for actionbar   -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/Navigation_Drawer_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Navigation_Main_Layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

             
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me why it's working with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` and it's not when using `getChildFragmentManager()`. When i should use getChildFragmentManager() inside viewpager's  fragment (child fragments).

I also tried with `getParentFragmentManager()` but getting same error.

Comment: Why are you using `getChildFragmentManager()` if the view isn't in that fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake the view is the toolbar button but its same for other views belongs to the fragment, like fab button has same issue if i dont use support fragment manager

Comment: No, 'the view' I mean is the view `R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout`. That isn't in the fragment, so why would the `childFragmentManager` know about it? It only knows about things in the fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It's a layout of activity container, you can check the XML layout i put in question and that layout belong to activites so i guess that's how fragment replace/add by main activity container

Comment: @ianhanniballake As you can see `getSupportFragmentManager()` working inside viewpage's fragment transactions but it should work with `getChildFragmentManager`. What's wrong with my code i don't get it.  The fragment container in main activity `R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout` should replace with `childFragmentManager `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Fragment Manager guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#access), which FragmentManager you should be using depends entirely on where the layout is:

[image: Ownership of each layout in an Activity with nested fragments]

The important being that a child fragment **must be placed within its parent's layout** - they are required to be nested within one another, in the same way that the Fragments themselves are nested within one another.

This is explained in the other picture from the documentation, which explains the relationship between each Fragment and the FragmentManagers:

[image: Relationship between each level of the hierarchy and the given FragmentManager]

In your case, you tried `getChildFragmentManager()`, but your `R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout` is not part of the Fragment's layout, so this crashes.

Then you tried using `getParentFragmentManager()`, but your `R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout` isn't in the parent fragment's layout either (since this is the Fragment 1 that contains your ViewPager).

Your `R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout` is in your activity's layout, which means the only valid FragmentManager you can use to put a Fragment in your activity's layout (but not inside any fragment), is the Activity's `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: This answer is really useful to me and kind of better explanation than the official documentation. And i can see it will help many whoever going to have problems with FM. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know its an issue but you can try it.
instead of :
**getChildFragmentManager()**

Use :
**getSupportFragmentManager()**

Or you can create the below method and call it when you want by passing the fragment which you want to load.

```
 private void callFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_id, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

You can see more about it from [here](https://fluttertpoint.com/navigation-drawer-android-studio-example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you can see in question i already mentioned that `getSupportFragmentManager` is working in my case but as other si post and documentation i should use child fragment manager and why it's not working in me case